# My program seems to work fine on debugger but it doesn't work on my console (release mode)

Tags: c++, runtime-error, vscode-debugger

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

vector<string> GetRecords()
{
    std::vector<std::string> files;
    struct dirent *entry;
    DIR *dir = opendir("Directory/i'm/using");

    if (dir == NULL)
    {
        return files;
    }
    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        files.push_back(entry->d_name);
    }
    closedir(dir);

    return files;
}

class node
{
private:
    node *left;
    node *right;
    node *par;
    bool isExternal;
    int depth;
    int position;
    int num;

public:
    node() : isExternal(true), depth(0), position(0), num(0) {}
    node(int num) : num(num), depth(0), isExternal(true)
    {
        this->left = generate_left();
        this->right = generate_right();
    }
    node *get_left() { return left; }
    node *generate_left()
    {
        this->left = new node();
        left->par = this;
        left->depth = left->par->depth + 1;
        return left;
    }
    node *get_right() { return right; }
    node *generate_right()
    {
        this->right = new node();
        right->par = this;
        right->depth = right->par->depth + 1;
        return right;
    }
    void set_num(int num)
    {
        this->num = num;
        this->par->isExternal = false;
    }
    int get_num() { return this->num; }
    int get_depth() { return this->depth; }
    int get_position() { return this->position; }
    void set_position(int pos) { this->position = pos; }
    bool check_External() { return isExternal; }
};

class BinaryTree
{
private:
    node root;
    queue<node *> ptr_queue;
    int max_depth;
    int max_width;

public:
    BinaryTree(int num) : root(num), max_width(0), max_depth(0)
    {
        ptr_queue.push(root.generate_left());
        ptr_queue.push(root.generate_right());
    }
    ~BinaryTree()
    {
        while (!ptr_queue.empty())
        {
            node *temp_ptr = ptr_queue.front();
            delete temp_ptr;
            ptr_queue.pop();
        }
    }

    void add(int num)
    {
        node *temp_ptr = ptr_queue.front();
        ptr_queue.push(temp_ptr->generate_left());
        ptr_queue.push(temp_ptr->generate_right());
        if (num == -1)
        {
            if (ptr_queue.size() == 0)
                return;
            ptr_queue.pop();
        }
        else
        {
            temp_ptr->set_num(num);
            ptr_queue.pop();
        }
        return;
    }
    void traverse() { traverse(&root); }
    void traverse(node *ptr_node)
    {
        if (ptr_node->get_num() == 0)
            return;
        if (ptr_node->check_External())
        {
            if (ptr_node->get_depth() > max_depth)
                max_depth = ptr_node->get_depth();
            ptr_node->set_position(max_width++);
            return;
        }
        traverse(ptr_node->get_left());
        ptr_node->set_position(max_width++);
        traverse(ptr_node->get_right());
    }

    void fill_zero(int **arr)
    {
        // when traverse() is finished max_width gets extra +1 because of ++ operator, while max_depth doesn't. So it needs extra +1
        for (int i = 0; i < max_depth + 1; ++i)
        {
            arr[i] = new int[max_width];
            for (int j = 0; j < max_width; ++j)
            {
                arr[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    void fill_array(int **arr) { fill_array(&root, arr); }
    void fill_array(node *ptr_node, int **arr)
    {
        if (ptr_node->get_num() == 0)
            return;
        if (ptr_node->check_External())
        {
            arr[ptr_node->get_depth()][ptr_node->get_position()] = ptr_node->get_num();
            return;
        }
        fill_array(ptr_node->get_left(), arr);
        arr[ptr_node->get_depth()][ptr_node->get_position()] = ptr_node->get_num();
        fill_array(ptr_node->get_right(), arr);
    }

    void print(int **arr)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < max_depth + 1; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < max_width; ++j)
                cout << arr[i][j] << "\t";
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    node get_root() { return root; }
    int get_depth() { return max_depth; }
    int get_width() { return max_width; }
};

void Macro(string path_file, int *check)
{
    queue<int> inputs;
    ifstream input(path_file);
    int num = 0;
    int length = 0;

    while (input >> num)
        inputs.push(num);
    length = inputs.size();

    // for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    // {
    //     cout << inputs.front() << endl;
    //     inputs.pop();
    // }
    BinaryTree tree(inputs.front());
    inputs.pop();
    for (int i = 1; i < length; ++i)
    {
        tree.add(inputs.front());
        inputs.pop();
    }
    tree.traverse();
    int **arr = new int *[tree.get_depth()];
    tree.fill_zero(arr);
    tree.fill_array(arr);
    cout << (*check)++ << endl;
    tree.print(arr);
    cout << endl;

    input.close();
    // cout << file << endl;
}

int main()
{
    string path = "Directory/i'm/using";
    vector<string> files;
    int *check = new int;
    *check = 0;

    files = GetRecords();
    // erase first three elements
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        files.erase(files.begin());

    for (auto file : files)
    {
        string path_file = path + file;
        cout << path_file << endl;
        Macro(path_file, check);
    }

    cout << "Ended" << endl;
    return 0;
    // test.print();
}
```

Here is my whole code.

The program's purpose is to get the input from files in directory and make binary tree.
The condition is given input is integer ranging from 1 to 999.
If program read -1 then it skips that position of the node and move next to it.

Here is some example

*input*

```
933 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

*output*

```
933
```

*input*

```
60 889 331 230 115 -1 229 652 -1 276 282
```

*output*

```
  0   0   0   0   0   0  60   0   0
  0   0 889   0   0   0   0 331   0
  0 230   0   0 115   0   0   0 229
652   0   0 276   0 282   0   0   0
```

*input*

```
231 580 -1 600 449 -1 -1 408 109 -1 451 -1 -1
```

*output*

```
  0   0   0   0   0   0 231
  0   0   0 580   0   0   0
  0 600   0   0 449   0   0
408   0 109   0   0 451   0
```

I hope you get it by now.
So, to make that I made program while measure the whole length and width of array by `BinaryTree.traverse()`
Fill it with zero by `BinaryTree.fill_zero()`, and change the place where I need to by `BinaryTree.fill_array()`.

And It seems work fine by logic, except it doesn't work on compiled exe file.

Program stops without getting out of the loop, so I'm guessing is runtime error.
But I can't know what is causing it because the debugger prints out without any problem.

The program I'm using is VSCode and compiler is g++.
Hope someone help me to find what is the problem and why debug works while release version fails.
https://ibb.co/4pVKMJH (result of debugger)
https://ibb.co/cDd1gvL (result of release)

Thank you for reading it. Have a nice day!

Comment: It could happen that the debugger initialize data to be zero, which for pointers means they will be null-pointers. If you have checks for null-pointers, they will work in the debugger. But outside the debugger these pointers will be *indeterminate* (read garbage) and the program might believe that they are not null and continue to use these invalid pointers leading to *undefined behavior*. Use the GCC sanitizers to help find the problems. And review your code to make sure all pointers are initialized and checked properly.

Comment: As an example: The `node` default constructor doesn't initialize the `left` and `right` pointers. Will you ever default-construct a `node` object? And the `BinaryTree` class breaks [the rules of three, five and zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). That could be an issue as well.

Comment: And why `int *check = new int;`? Why not plain `int check = 0;` and use the pointer-to operator `&` (as in `&check`) when a pointer to it is needed? Or pass it by reference instead. The less pointers your code have, the more robust it will be, with less possible causes or errors.

Comment: You shown a lot of code, but this simple two line program has problems: `int main() { node n; std::cout << n.left->num; }`

Comment: *"Here is my whole code."* -- please don't. You should boil your problem down to a [mre]. Remove code until you cannot remove any more without the problem disappearing (or being replaced by a different problem). This is more challenging when undefined behavior is involved (a reasonable guess in this case), but at least put in the effort. Keep in mind that the [mre] does not need to preserve your intended functionality; it needs only demonstrate that the functionality is different between debug and release modes. (Also, since you started your question with code, you might want to review [ask].)

Comment: @Some programmer dude Thank you for answering! Didn't know about gcc sanitzers and exist the way to check the problem beside the debugger! So the lesson is initialize every single code if possible. Got it! And about rule of three/five(). Can it be the reason to act different in debugger?

Comment: @JaMiT I'm sorry. But I'm still learning and since I faced something I've never seen before I wanted to make sure it is right. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: @이가원 *"But I'm still learning"* -- this is a reason why you should work on a minimal reproducible example (MRE). The process of creating a MRE tends to be educational, or at least enlightening. Usually when I request a MRE, I am trying to trick the asker into learning something, and the fact that Stack Overflow requires a MRE is only my secondary motivation. ;)